# C++ Using a single class in multiple other classes - Multiple definition error when compiling

Tags: c++, visual-studio, arduino

I downloaded a library for the arduino to communicate with an MCP23017 chip via I2C. My goal is to use this one class in various files to have different functions, essentially a library of things to do with this chip.

After building the code to run a 7-segment multiplexed display, everything compiled fine and was able to load onto the arduino. After writing another class to use a second chip for inputs only, i started getting compile errors due to multiple definitions of the base class.  I'm used to coding in VB, not C++, so having to define classes like this is pretty confusing, and I am not sure what to do to fix it.

Here is the error: (this is only a snippet of the error, since the gist of this section is good enough I think. Every routine in the Adafruit_MCP23017.cpp file has this error.)

```
Adafruit_MCP23017.cpp.o (symbol from plugin)*: In function Adafruit_MCP23017::bitForPin(unsigned char)
(.text+0x0)*: multiple definition of Adafruit_MCP23017::readGPIO(unsigned char)
Adafruit_MCP23017.cpp.o (symbol from plugin)*: (.text+0x0): first defined here
```

Mainfile Header:

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include "SevenSegmentDisplay_MCP23017.h"
#include "I2C_Input_MCP23017.h"

SevenSegmentDisplay SSD;
I2C_Input_MCP23017 INP;
```

SevenSegmentDisplay.h Header:

```
#pragma once
#ifndef _Adafruit_MCP23017_H_   
    #include <Adafruit_MCP23017.h>
#endif
#include <Arduino.h> // Need for serial output and 'delay' function
```

SevenSegmentDisplay.cpp Header:

```
#include "SevenSegmentDisplay_MCP23017.h"
```

I2C_Input_MCP23017.h header:

```
#pragma once
#include <Adafruit_MCP23017.h>
#include <Arduino.h> // Need for serial output and 'delay' function
```

I2C_Input_MCP23017.cpp header:

```
#include "I2C_Input_MCP23017.h"
```

**SOLUTION EDIT:**
After reading the answer someone posted, I found the problem. I didn't think the base class was up to snuff (lack of comments on the routines, making it pretty hard to use, since you had no description of what each routine accepted as variables or what it did.) When doing this, I included it into the solution. **The problem was that it was including it from the library folder and the solution itself** (even though the solution only referenced the files from the library itself, no new files were created). I removed the reference to the class in question (highlighted in the picture below) and the program compiled perfectly. (tested by adding them back in which resulted in the same faults).

TL;DR: If you have the file in your library already, don't include it in the solution, as it seems to want to grab it twice. Once when #included and once in the solution explorer.

[Here was the problem:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JmaoY.png)

Comment: If you're not used to coding C++, I would suggest first starting out with a beginner course, book, or online tutorial for learning C++ from the ground up. Frankly speaking, you're starting at the wrong end on the pool here, and trying to learn the language by stumbling through a desired implementation will blind you to a lot of the pitfalls and coding practices that are most-certainly desired when working with ICs.

Comment: The code you have provided is not enough to identify what the problem is. My best guess is that you defined a member function in your header.

Comment: Clarification: I've taken 2 c# courses, but that was almost 2 years ago. So while I understand the majority of it, I just never understood classes in an implementation like this.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you have the Adafruit_MCP23017 library (.c and .h files) in two places in your Arduino  /libraries directory.

Probably (probably!) in both /libraries/Adafruit_MCP23017/ and /libraries/SevenSegmentDisplay_MCP23017/utility/

Adafruit make their libraries beginner proof by including any required sub-libraries in the download archives. But it confuses things as soon as you try to use the sub-library directly.

If this is the case then you will need to modify the SevenSegmentDisplay_MCP23017.h file to change from

```
#include <utility/Adafruit_MCP23017.h>
```

to

```
#include <Adafruit_MCP23017.h>
```

and delete Adafruit_MCP23017.h and Adafruit_MCP23017.c from the /libraries/SevenSegmentDisplay_MCP23017/utility/ 
directory.

Comment: Personally, I thought that that specific library was not beginner proof at all. There was no comments in anything describing how to use the library or what valid values can be passed to the routines.    That said, could it be because I put a link to those files in the project itself as well? (I was adding in the comments so that when calling a routine, it had an explanation while hovering).  I should also mention that all of the files are in a single project folder together currently (except for the adafruit library which is just linked with 'add existing item'.